WENX Tokens Price not showing
Hello phantom wallet help,
I'm having problem with my $WENX tokens on my phantom account.
can you guy's please help me to solve this problem?
thanks.
wallet solana address:  49N1H6xd3vavyaZ8vaZFtFfoCdBtJGycaUxQh9hr9YBU
